# Convert string to required json format

Tags: python, json, logic

I am using json-logic library for my project .
I want to convert user input string to json-logic format using python.

user input string:

```
intent == serviceRequest and entities.entity== charges and entities.value ==getRoamingCharges or entities.entity==plans and entities.value ==data plans
```

required json format:

```
{"and":[
{"==" :[{"var":"intent"},'serviceRequest']},
{"or":[
{"and":[{"some" : [ {"var":"entities"}, {"==":[{"var":"entity"}, "charges"]} ]},
{"some" : [ {"var":"entities"}, {"==":[{"var":"value"}, "getRoamingCharges"]} ]}]
},{"and":[
  {"some" : [ {"var":"entities"}, {"==":[{"var":"entity"}, "plans"]} ]},
 {"some" : [ {"var":"entities"}, {"==":[{"var":"value"}, "data plans"]} ]}
 ]}]}  ]}
```

The user input string logic(and or operators) will always be dynamic .
Can anyone help me on this.
I have tried doing this with pyparsing library but i am unable to parse the string to required json format.
Thanks

Comment: If you post your pyparsing code and tag with `pyparsing` tag, you will get more help on this. Or post on the pyparsing sub-reddit for more interactive/extended discussion. You can also see a number of search query parsers and boolean expression parsers on the pyparsing GitHub repo in the examples directory.